# "Resample" a timestamp according to its frequency

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas `Timestamp` with a datetime and frequency associated. However, the datetime seems to be independent of the frequency. For instance,

```
>>> t = pd.Timestamp('2018-6-6', freq='W-FRI')
>>> t
Timestamp('2018-06-06 00:00:00')
```

June 6, 2018 is not a Friday. How can I get June 1, 2018 (the previous Friday) from this `Timestamp`? (If the `Timestamp` were June 1, 2018 then it should return June 1, 2018.) The following works but seems too verbose.

```
>>> friday = (pd.date_range(t + pd.Timedelta('1D'), 
                            periods=1, 
                            freq='W-FRI')
              - 1)[0]
>>> friday
Timestamp('2018-06-01 00:00:00', freq='W-FRI')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around, it seems that `rollback` is the perfect method for this. (If we'd wanted the next Friday instead of the previous Friday we could use `rollforward`.) There are two ways to create the offset object with a frequency of `W-FRI`:

```
# Method 1
>>> from pandas.tseries.offsets import Week
>>> w_fri = Week(weekday=4) # Mon == 0, Tue == 1, ..., Sun = 6
>>> w_fri
<Week: weekday=4>

# Method 2
>>> from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset
>>> w_fri = to_offset('W-FRI')
>>> w_fri
<Week: weekday=4>
```

Then to do the rollback,

```
>>> w_fri.rollback(pd.Timestamp('2019-1-17'))  # A Thursday
Timestamp('2019-01-11 00:00:00')
>>> w_fri.rollback(pd.Timestamp('2019-1-18'))  # A Friday
Timestamp('2019-01-18 00:00:00')
```

More info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects)

Answer (score 2):

**OR** we could use an if-statement to not move the date if it is friday (4) already. Thanks to **@Ben.T** we can compare it to the defined freq-weekday and thus make it a bit more generic.

```
import pandas as pd

t = pd.Timestamp('2018-6-7', freq='W-FRI')
friday = t if t.weekday() == t.freq.weekday else t-1

print(friday)
```

Returns:

```
2018-06-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: This moves a friday to the previous friday rather than leave it unchanged

Comment: Better, sure, but I don't like needing to specify the frequency twice. If I change `'W-FRI'` to `'W-MON'` then I also need to change 4 to 0.

Comment: @BallpointBen then you can use `t.freq.weekday` to not have to specified the day again: `friday = t if t.weekday() == t.freq.weekday else t-1`

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use the methods `weekday` of t and the fact that the `freq.weekday` is accessible from t:

```
t - pd.Timedelta(days = (t.weekday() - t.freq.weekday)%7 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> friday = [d for d in pd.date_range(end='2018-6-6', periods=7, freq='D') 
      if d.dayofweek == 4]
>>> print(friday)

[Timestamp('2018-06-01 00:00:00', freq='D')]
```